# oooBasic : how to assign a key to a macro, programmatically?

Tags: openoffice-basic

I would like to assign, programmatically, a macro to a function key (instead of changing manually this assignation).

How could I do this ?

Comment: What key do you want to assign, and in what environment - Writer, Calc, a form or a dialog window?

Comment: mm, for example : F12. On Writer .:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to do something like this is to add a key handler to `ThisComponent.CurrentController` using the [addKeyHandler()](https://www.openoffice.org/api/docs/common/ref/com/sun/star/awt/XUserInputInterception.html#addKeyHandler) method.  This makes it possible to intercept the keystroke and then cancel it so that it doesn't do whatever else the key was assigned to.

There is an example at https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=45&t=33914.

Write a macro that adds the listener, like `sStartXKeyHandler` in the example.  Then assign that macro to a [document event](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/DevGuide/OfficeDev/Document_Events) such as `OnLoad`.

Comment: mm ! It works very well !! oEvent.KeyCode = 779 when F12 is pressed, so I can set KeyHandler_KeyPressed to True in this case (and do what I want). Thanks a lot, Jim, exactly what I needed. Thanks!